# Power loss in an RC circuit with very low resistance

Tags: capacitor, antenna, charge

I read at some point that an RC circuit with extremely low resistance might end up not being more efficient than one with higher resistance because the voltage change will be so fast that the capacitor will act like an antenna?  Does this occur if the time constant is so low that metal the length of the capacitor would be able to act as an antenna at that frequency?

Comment: "*... might end up not being more efficient ...*". Efficient at doing what?

Comment: Storing energy.

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.smpstech.com/charge.htm

Comment: I voted to close this. Mainly because it is not clear what you are asking. If you can do something to make the question more clear I will retract my vote. If you are asking whether a capacitor can radiate RF waves into space, the answer is yes. If you are asking whether an increase in series R can make a capacitor more efficient, then the answer is no. However it is not clear what you mean by efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to charge a capacitor via a resistor from a fixed voltage DC source then the energy you lose (to heat) in the resistor is always the same irrespective of how large or how small that resistor is. The charge time (as dictated by RC) is irrelevant to the problem.

You don't need to worry about EM radiation as a factor in order to to prove this i.e. you can assume there will be no radiation other than as heat from the resistor.